# How to return the equivalent of "None" in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

If I have some branching operation in TensorFlow, how can I return a None tensor in one branch, and a filled tensor in the other?

For example:

```
tensor_result = tf.cond(
    pred=tf.less(0, 1),
    fn1=...,  # here I would like to return None
    fn2=tf.constant([1, 2, 3]))
```

And then `tensor_result` can be tested for being None later in the graph.

Is there currently any way of doing this? Currently I am filling a tensor with NaNs, but I imagine this isn't very efficient.

Comment: Why not using another boolean mask tensor "is_none" and fill it up with zero or one. How do you want to use the "is none" information later?

Comment: You could return a ()-shaped tensor consisting of a single NaN, although such dynamic shaping disable some optimizations

Answer (score 2):

Tensors are containers for numerical data types, e.g.
`tf.convert_to_tensor(None)` raises `ValueError: None values not supported.`. So there is **no** *None*-Tensor.

I would do it like:

```
mask = tf.less(0, 1) # return a tensor of type bool
filtered = tf.cast(mask, unfiltered.dtype) * unfiltered
```

I would *never* add NaNs on my own to the computation. They strongly indicate that something went wrong.

Comment: My issue with this is what if `unfiltered` contains zero values? If I wish to branch based on whether `unfiltered` is None or not, I could not tell the difference between intentional zeros and zeros resulting from the filter.